# raising keyboard pressing on a text field

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to raise my keyboard when i press on a determinate UITextField, so I create a touch down action, but at the first call it doesn't work, by second call it work fine.
here's the code (naturally keyboardSize is a global variable with CGSize type):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];     
}  

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
 keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

}


- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
[self moveFrameToVerticalPosition:0.0f forDuration:0.3f];
}


- (void)moveFrameToVerticalPosition:(float)position forDuration:(float)duration {
CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
frame.origin.y = position;

[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
    self.view.frame = frame;
}];
}

- (IBAction)insert:(id)sender {

float newVerticalPosition = - keyboardSize.height;

[self moveFrameToVerticalPosition:newVerticalPosition forDuration:0.0f];

}
```

Comment: The while loop does not look like a good idea...?

Comment: Yes, you're right I had added it to try to fix the problem and i forgot to remove it before posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

In `keyboardWillShow:` add:

`[self moveFrameToVerticalPosition:-keyboardSize.height forDuration:0.0f];`

You don't really need `insert:`.

Comment: No, i've 3 text field but only when i press on two it must raise.